# Can Visual Studio Code Editor be used for TeX editor (for example)?

Tags: visual-studio, tex

I like Visual Studio Code Editor such as, #region, collapsing, etc.

Is it possible to use it to edit and compile TeX?

Thank  you.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve that but the simplest is using [Custom Build Rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfsbz6cw%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

Comment: @xport what do you mean by attach? you specify in the build rule to build with latex (you give a path to it).